# Does Blender have a C++ API?

Tags: python, add-on

The docs tantalizingly hint at a C++ API in Blender that allows for creating new mesh modifiers, object types and shader nodes:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_overview.html

I'm unable to find any documentation on this API.  What I have found are some old forum posts that suggest there was one a long time ago, but it got removed because too few were using it.

I would like to create my own object type (I'm trying to copy a Maya plugin that does something similar).  This seems impossible with the limitations of the Python API.  Is there a C++ API I can use, or would I need to fork Blender to add a new object type to it?

Comment: The parts that refer to C or C++ mean that these features would require modifications of Blender itself. There is no C++ API. The only way to currently access raw data structures from Python is [`as_pointer()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.bpy_struct.as_pointer). Creating an add-on that adds new primitives is entirely possible. Take a look at the code for the [Extra Objects add-on](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/add_mesh_extra_objects/).

Comment: The Extra Add On objects aren't quite what I'm looking for.  They're just interactive ways to create new mesh objects.  I'd like to create a new type of object that has properties you can still modify after it's created.  Sort of how empties or metaballs are different sorts of objects.

Comment: A fully parametric object type would require the modification of Blender's code and likely quite extensive changes. While new contributions are always welcome and parametric objects are certainly something the community is interested in, it's not an ideal first project when you're unfamiliar with Blender's codebase.